# Making a variablewrapgridview adjust dynamically

Tags: c#, gridview, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm implementing a gridview where I end up having some of the grid items bigger/smaller than others. I tried following Jerry Nixon's example given here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

However, his grid sizes are based off of the index numbers of the colors used. I'm wondering if there is a way to have my variablegridview dynamically size based off of the amount of content I'm trying to put into the gridview. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure what you're asking with regards to "dynamically size based off of the amount of content". Do you want them to be smaller if there are more that need to be fit in a given row/column? If you know how many items are in the list, then you can use an attached property (like he did in the blog post) to attach the relative size of it. You could also have the list change the ItemHeight and ItemWidth of the grid based on the number of items.

Comment: Sorry, I should have come back to edit this. I was able to figure it out, and use an attached property. Thank you anyways @NateDiamond